# Extract a specific field from JSON output using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml field like below

```
<INPUT>{"data":"abc1234":"format":"text"}</INPUT>
```

I need to extract only data value from the JSON string, in this case it abc1234

i am expecting the following output

```
<OUTPUT>abc1234</OUPUT>
```

Any help here?

Comment: Which XSLT 2 processor do you use? No chance it really is an XSLT 3 processor or can be updated, like Saxon 9.7 or earlier, to Saxon 9.8, 9.9 or 10, to use the JSON support in XSLT 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your input actually contains a *valid* JSON in the form of:

```
<INPUT>{"data":"abc1234","format":"text"}</INPUT>
```

you could do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="INPUT">
    <OUTPUT>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&quot;data&quot;:&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
    </OUTPUT>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this will fail if the formatting of the input JSON changes.

Comment: How do you fetch the "format" value

Comment: Change the formula to use `format` instead of `data`.

Answer (score -1):

With XSLT 3.0 you can use the [`parse-json()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-functions-31-20170321/#func-parse-json) function, and then select the `data` property value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="INPUT">
        <OUTPUT><xsl:value-of select="parse-json(text())?data"/></OUTPUT>          
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If your data is JSON. The example is not, you have `:` separating the properties, instead of `,`.